# How can one value a Bermudan option?

Tags: option-pricing, hedging, american-options, valuation, bermudan

A Bermudan option allows early exercise at predefined dates,  e.g. at maturity equal to $t_1$, $t_2$, $t_3$,...;

hence , would its value be the sum of 3 discounted European options with 1-year maturity?

Comment: The easiest way for Bermudan option pricing is the Binomial tree method. http://eprints.maths.ox.ac.uk/789/1/Thom.pdf

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki This is a general numerical method similar to MC Simulation, but I was looking for an analytic approach.

Comment: No, since it can only be exercised once.

Comment: @emcor , you can use Fourier-Cosine Method for Pricing Bermudan Options.[link](https://quanto.inria.fr/pdf_html/ap_cosine_doc/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we should first define some
notation before discussing pricing. Let $t_0$ be initial time and $ t_1, . . . , t_M$ be pre-specified exercise dates with $t_0 < t_1 < · · · < t_M = T$ , the final maturity, and $Δt = t_m−t_{m−1}$. Without a loss of generality it is assumed exercise dates are equidistant. To price a Bermudan option, its value is split into two parts, the continuation value and the immediate exercise payoff.
At time  $t_{m−1}$, the value of $ v(x, t_{m−1})$ consists of the continuation value and the early exercise payoff value.An approximated continuation value, assuming the option is not exercised in the current period, is ([look article](https://quanto.inria.fr/pdf_html/ap_cosine_doc/))
\begin{align}
c(x,t_{m-1})=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} Re\left[\phi\left(\frac{k\pi}{b-a};y|x\right)exp\left(-ik\pi\frac{a}{b-a}\right)\right]V_k(t_m)
\end{align}
where

$x:$ be the modeled quantity at t, often the log asset price.

$y:$ be the modeled quantity at T, often the log asset price.

$f(y|x):$ be the probability density function under the pricing measure.

and
\begin{align}
V_k(t_m)=\frac{2}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}v(y,t_m) cos\left(k\pi\frac{y-a}{b-a}\right)dy
\end{align}

for more details, you can see [this article.](https://quanto.inria.fr/pdf_html/ap_cosine_doc/)

Comment: How does a cos() function come into $V_{k}$?